# react-modal invoke on link click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router-dom, react-modal

Using [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal), I need to show the modal on click of the hyperlink either through an anchor tag or react-router-dom link.

Example: click on register hyperlink and register form modal should open.

```
handleClick() =>{
 <ReactModal/>
}
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href='' onclick='handleClick()'>check</>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Samathingamajig I'm new to frontend & react and searched online, checked other stuff to resolve the issue before posting it here but couldn't find a solution. kndly do remove the downvote

Comment: you can't have a function called `function()`

Comment: it was example outline which i am facing, changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `onClick` event handler for link. On the handler you can use `preventDefault` to stop navigating to the linked url. Please check below example.

```js
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
```

```html
<a
  href="https://github.com"
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setModalVisible(true);
  }}
>
  Github
</a>
```

```html
<Modal
  isOpen={modalVisible}
>
  ...
</Modal>
```